# Is there a flaw in this proof? Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Say $(a_n)$ is a positive and real sequence with
$$\large\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=l.$$

I am reading a proof of the fact that $\large a_n^\frac{1}{n}\to l$, where it firstly finds $N$ such that $n\gt N$ gives $\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-l\rvert\lt\epsilon$, and so
$$\large\rvert a_n^\frac{1}{n}\lvert=
\rvert\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}...\frac{a_2}{a_1}a_1\rvert^\frac{1}{n}
\leq(l+\epsilon)^\frac{n-N}{n}\lvert\frac{a_N}{a_{N-1}}...\frac{a_2}{a_1}a_1\rvert^\frac{1}{n}
\leq(l+\epsilon)\lvert\frac{a_N}{a_{N-1}}...\frac{a_2}{a_1}a_1\rvert^\frac{1}{n}
$$
but I do not see why the power of $(l+\epsilon)^\frac{n-N}{n}$ can be dropped. What if $l+\epsilon\lt1$? Surely the above is incorrect in this case.

Comment: Presumably because $\frac{n-N}{n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$ ($N$ fixed).

Comment: If $l+\epsilon\lt 1$, don't we have $(l+\epsilon)^\frac{n-N}{n}\gt(l+\epsilon)$ for all $n\gt N$?

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're saying.  Do you have a citation for this proof?  I'd like to see the context.

Comment: This can be easily fixed by taking limsup and liminf of the inequalities. Then the term $(l+\epsilon) ^{(n-N) /n} $ has limit $(l+\epsilon) $.

Comment: Another approach may be to consider $b_n=1/a_n$ if  $l<1$ and then $b_{n+1}/b_n\to 1/l>1$.